# Jackson Custom Deserializer

Tags: android, json, serialization, jackson

I am using a custom deserializer for one property in an object.

```
public class Leg {

    @JsonProperty("carrier_code")
    private String carrierCode;
    @JsonProperty("carrier_name")
    private String carrierName;
    @JsonProperty("mode_of_transport")
    private String modeOfTransport;
    private String provider;
    @JsonProperty("leg_id")
    private int legId;
    @JsonDeserialize(using = PriceContainerDeserializer.class)
    @JsonProperty("price_container")
    private PriceContainer priceContainer;
    private Schedule schedule;
```

}

The problem I have is that everything is parsed find apart from the schedule. If I remove the custom deserializer that schedule is parsed. How can I solve this problem?

Here is the custom deserializer

```
public class PriceContainerDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<PriceContainer> {

    @Override
    public PriceContainer deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        PriceContainer priceContainer = new PriceContainer();
        jsonParser.nextValue();
        priceContainer.setCurrency(jsonParser.getText());
        jsonParser.nextValue();
        jsonParser.nextValue();
        jsonParser.nextValue();
        jsonParser.nextValue();
        priceContainer.setAmount(jsonParser.getDoubleValue());
        return priceContainer;
    }
}
```

JSON sample -

```
{
                        "carrier_code": "car",
                        "carrier_name": "Car2go",
                        "leg_id": "1",
                        "mode_of_transport": "car_sharing",
                        "pre_legs": [
                            {
                                "mode_of_transport": "walk",
                                "schedule": {
                                    "a": {
                                        "date": 1387152000,
                                        "lat": 52.529985,
                                        "lng": 13.403,
                                        "name": "Torstra\u00dfe 109",
                                        "time": 1387192515,
                                        "time_delta": 0
                                    },
                                    "b": {
                                        "date": 1387152000,
                                        "lat": 52.52761,
                                        "lng": 13.3997,
                                        "name": "Auguststra\u00dfe 52, 10119 Berlin",
                                        "time": 1387192774,
                                        "time_delta": 0
                                    },
                                    "distance": 346,
                                    "duration": 259
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "price_container": {
                            "currency": "EUR",
                            "is_bookable": false,
                            "prices": [
                                {
                                    "amount": 377,
                                    "currency": "EUR",
                                    "price_name": "Car2go",
                                    "price_type": 0,
                                    "tarif_id": ""
                                }
                            ],
                            "reservation_price": 0,
                            "selected_price_index": 0
                        },
                        "provider": "car2go",
                        "schedule": {
                            "a": {
                                "date": 1387152000,
                                "lat": 52.52761,
                                "lng": 13.3997,
                                "name": "Auguststra\u00dfe 52, 10119 Berlin",
                                "time": 1387192774,
                                "time_delta": 0
                            },
                            "b": {
                                "date": 1387152000,
                                "lat": 52.514658,
                                "lng": 13.465346,
                                "name": "Samariterstr.",
                                "time": 1387193314,
                                "time_delta": 0
                            },
                            "distance": 4828.0199999999995,
                            "duration": 540
                        },
                        "sub_legs": [
                            {
                                "carrier_code": "car",
                                "carrier_name": "Car2go",
                                "properties": {
                                    "engine_type": "CE",
                                    "exterior_state": "UNACCEPTABLE",
                                    "fuel_level": 48,
                                    "interior_state": "UNACCEPTABLE",
                                    "license_plate_number": "B-GO2798"
                                },
                                "schedule": {
                                    "a": {
                                        "date": 1387152000,
                                        "lat": 52.52761,
                                        "lng": 13.3997,
                                        "name": "Auguststra\u00dfe 52, 10119 Berlin",
                                        "time": 1387192774,
                                        "time_delta": 0
                                    },
                                    "b": {
                                        "date": 1387152000,
                                        "lat": 52.514658,
                                        "lng": 13.465346,
                                        "name": "Samariterstr.",
                                        "time": 1387193314,
                                        "time_delta": 0
                                    },
                                    "distance": 4828.0199999999995,
                                    "duration": 540
                                },
                                "sub_mode_of_transport": {
                                    "id": [
                                        10,
                                        "car2go"
                                    ],
                                    "mode_of_transport": "car_sharing",
                                    "name": "car2go"
                                },
                                "vehicle_name": "B-GO2798"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
```

**EDIT**

So my deserializer now looks like this

```
public class PriceContainerDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<PriceContainer> {

    @Override
    public PriceContainer deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        PriceContainer priceContainer = new PriceContainer();
        jsonParser.nextValue();
        priceContainer.setCurrency(jsonParser.getText());
        jsonParser.nextValue();
        jsonParser.nextValue();
        jsonParser.nextValue();
        jsonParser.nextValue();
        priceContainer.setAmount(jsonParser.getDoubleValue());
        jsonParser.nextValue();
        jsonParser.nextValue();
        jsonParser.nextValue();
        jsonParser.nextValue();
        jsonParser.nextValue();
        jsonParser.nextValue();
        jsonParser.nextValue();
        jsonParser.nextValue();
        jsonParser.nextValue();
        return priceContainer;
    }
}
```

is that the best way to do it?

Comment: you have to "go outside" price and price_container in your deserialize method ... after `jsonParser.getDoubleValue()` (assuming that your PriceContainterDeserializer is working) "parser is inside price object" ... you have to read data until you: find end of object, end of array, end of object ... now parser should be in proper state to read rest of "Leg" object

Comment: yeah that works. Do you want to write is up as an answer or shall I?